# Freecell: How many cells are used in one "supermove"

Tags: free-cell

A supermove in Freecell is when you move more than one card at the same time and automatically takes into account any free cells and free columns you have in order to maximise the number you can move.
The exact formula is not a problem: 2^emptycolumns * (freecells+1)

My question is, when I make a supermove how can I calculate how many moves were made to cells.
I am not talking about how many cells were used. This would be easy to calculate.
What I mean is, for example, you move 10 cards because you have 4 free cells and 3 free columns, it is simulating a number of steps that include moving to cells and columns and back.
So, how many moves were to cells?

Edit: [FreeCell: How many cards can be moved at once?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45155/freecell-how-many-cards-can-be-moved-at-once) does not answer my question. That just gives the formula to calculate how many cards can be moved but not how many cell moves are needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FreeCell: How many cards can be moved at once?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45155/freecell-how-many-cards-can-be-moved-at-once)

Comment: @Sneftel That only gives me the formula to calculate how many cards I can move. It doesn't tell me how many cells I use when making those moves.

Comment: There's no single answer to that. If you have enough free cells and free columns, when making a particular supermove you could choose to use all the free cells or none of them.

Comment: @Sneftel I figured that but wondered if there was a way to calculate the minimum number of cell moves you could use